# Angularjs : Inject ngProgress service in controller file using MEAN Stack

Tags: javascript, angularjs, mean-stack

**Note:** Need help with respect to MEAN stack implementation otherwise with respect to standalone html file where I can just include the script src to ngprogress.min.js, its working in that case.

Starting with what I have tried is:

Installed ngProgress bower module by bower install ngProgress.

**1st scenario**

Tried to access it in my controller by :

```
angular.module('articles').controller('ArticlesController', ['ngProgress',function(ngProgress) {

// getting undefined provider unpr error

ngProgress.start();

}]);
```

**2nd Scenario**

Tried using it through access through service, took hint from http://www.ng-newsletter.com/posts/d3-on-angular.html, this works sometimes I can include ngprogress.min.js in the html file. But then while using `ngProgress.start();` ngProgress is reported undefined.

Contoller code:

```
angular.module('articles').controller('ArticlesController', ['ngProgress',function(ngProgress) {

    // getting undefined provider unpr error

    ngProgress.start();

    }]);
```

Service Code:

```
'use strict';

angular.module('ngProgress', [])
    .factory('progressService', ['$document', '$q', '$rootScope', function($document, $q, $rootScope) {
        var d = $q.defer();
        function onScriptLoad() {
            // Load client in the browser
            $rootScope.$apply(function() { d.resolve(window.ngProgress); });
        }
        // Create a script tag with d3 as the source
        // and call our onScriptLoad callback when it
        // has been loaded
        var scriptTag = $document[0].createElement('script');
        scriptTag.type = 'text/javascript';
        scriptTag.async = true;
        scriptTag.src = 'bower_components/ngprogress/build/ngprogress.min.js';
        scriptTag.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (this.readyState === 'complete') { onScriptLoad(); }
        };
        scriptTag.onload = onScriptLoad;

        var s = $document[0].getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
        s.appendChild(scriptTag);

        return {
            ngProgress: function() { return d.promise; }
        };
    }]);
```

I have also tried using `packageName.angularDependencies(['ngProgress'])` and `packageName.aggregateAssets(js, ngprogress.min.js)` in app.js file of the package, it didnt helped too.

I am a newbee in Mean Stack.Please help I am stuck for days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to config/env/all.js or search for `all.js` in your project folder and add the ngprogress.min.js to the assets.lib.js file.
here is how it looks like

```
assets: {
    lib: {
        css: [
            'public/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css',
            'public/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap-theme.css',
        ],
        js: [
            'public/lib/angular/angular.js',
            'public/lib/angular-resource/angular-resource.js',
            'public/lib/angular-animate/angular-animate.js',
            'public/lib/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js',
            'public/lib/angular-ui-utils/ui-utils.js',
            'public/lib/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js'
        ]
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

The working solution is:

Goto file : config/assets.json

include ngProgress css and js in respective array like:

```
{
  "core": {
    "css": {
      "bower_components/build/css/Dist. min. css": [
        "bower_components/ngprogress/ngProgress.css"
      ]
    },
    "js": {
      "bower_components/build/js/dist.min.js": [
        "bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
        "bower_components/angular/angular.js",
        "bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js",
        "bower_components/angular-cookies/angular-cookies.js",
        "bower_components/angular-resource/angular-resource.js",
        "bower_components/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js",
        "bower_components/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap.js",
        "bower_components/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js",
        "bower_components/ngprogress/build/ngProgress.js"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Go to the controller to test or work on ngProgress object:

Inject the service dependency and module dependency, after successfull retrieval of ngProgress object use its methods and attributes accordingly

```
     angular.module('mean.articles',['ngProgress']).controller('ArticlesController', ['ngProgress',function(ngProgress) {

            ngProgress.start();
            ngProgress.set(40);

            }]);
```